# Incrementing pointer and assign a new value - Stack corruption

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote the following piece of code for a better demonstration of my problem:

```
int *ptr; 
int var;

var = 1;    // lets assume that the lvalue of "var" is 0x01000 
            // which is a fictitious address, but needed for further explanation of my thoughts

ptr = &var; // so ptr points to 0x01000, where the 4 byte integer "1" is stored

ptr++;      // pointer incrementing by 4 Bytes because we have a pointer of type integer
            // pointer now points to 0x01004

*ptr = 2;   // dereferencing of ptr and store the value "2" in 0x01004

            // I expected somethink like:
            // address| 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
            // 0x1000 | 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 ....
            // as the result of this code
```

I tried to describe my thought on this code in the comments, so you can correct me better.

When I run the Code, I get the runtime error "Stack around the variable 'var' was corrupted."

Comment: Yes, you are invoking *undefined behavior* by trying to access memory that has not been initialized.

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you intentionally write to a memory location that is not yours, then it crashes. Works as defined I would say. Under what circumstances should this be OK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
*ptr = 2;   // dereferencing of ptr and store the value "2" in 0x01004
```

is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Because `ptr` here doesn't point an address you can legally store something. `var` is just *one* `int` and after the `ptr++;` operation, whatever the address it points to, you can't dereference it.

If `var` were to be a block of `int`s such as:

```
int *ptr;
int var[5]; /* 5 int's */
var[0] = 1;

ptr = var; /* or, ptr = &var[0]; */
```

then you can increment and store something:

```
ptr++;

*ptr = 2; /* equivalent to assigning 2 to var[1] */
```